# Wired connection doens't work (RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller)

Tags: networking, ethernet

I'm new to linux and elemtaryOS, sorry for that ;)

I'm trying to describe my issue.

My wireless connection works fine, but I want to switch to wired connection because of the speed.
If I try to connect my computer with a patchcable to the router there is no connection. 
I try solve the issue by myself but I have no clue. Maybe a driver issue?

There are some outputs, maybe they help.

```
timo@timo-TA790GXB3:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] Passwort für timo: 
  *-network               
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Produkt: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:03:00.0
       Logischer Name: enp3s0
       Version: 03
       Seriennummer: 00:30:67:34:05:77
       Größe: 1Gbit/s
       Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       Ressourcen: irq:28 ioport:e800(Größe=256) memory:fdfff000-fdffffff memory:fdff8000-fdffbfff memory:febe0000-febfffff
  *-network
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Physische ID: 1
       Bus-Informationen: usb@8:1.2
       Logischer Name: wlx10feed194d1a
       Seriennummer: 10:fe:ed:19:4d:1a
       Fähigkeiten: ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=4.4.0-45-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.2.114 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn


timo@timo-TA790GXB3:~$ ifconfig -a
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:30:67:34:05:77  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:488 Fehler:0 Verloren:2 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:29877 (29.8 KB)  TX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:8950 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:8950 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1 
          RX-Bytes:697460 (697.4 KB)  TX-Bytes:697460 (697.4 KB)

wlx10feed194d1a Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 10:fe:ed:19:4d:1a  
          inet Adresse:192.168.2.114  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::4494:f0f1:6020:1cc8/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:15621 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:15431 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:10147911 (10.1 MB)  TX-Bytes:2202207 (2.2 MB)
```

It's obviously a luxury problem but it gets on my nerves.

Thank a lot for help

edit: there is syslog after connecting the lancable

```
Dec  4 17:50:09 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  768.317570] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
Dec  4 17:50:09 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  768.317584] ata2: EH complete
Dec  4 17:50:09 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  768.323495] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40c0000 action 0xe frozen
Dec  4 17:50:09 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  768.323499] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
Dec  4 17:50:09 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  768.323502] ata2: SError: { CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
Dec  4 17:50:09 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  768.323506] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec  4 17:50:09 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  768.323509] ata2: hard resetting link
Dec  4 17:50:09 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  768.941391] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
Dec  4 17:50:09 timo-TA790GXB3 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1480870209.7951] device (enp3s0): link disconnected
Dec  4 17:50:09 timo-TA790GXB3 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1480870209.7953] device (enp3s0): state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed') [30 20 40]
Dec  4 17:50:11 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  770.553689] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
Dec  4 17:50:11 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  770.553702] ata2: EH complete
Dec  4 17:50:11 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  770.557009] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40c0000 action 0xe frozen
Dec  4 17:50:11 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  770.557013] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
Dec  4 17:50:11 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  770.557016] ata2: SError: { CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
Dec  4 17:50:11 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  770.557020] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec  4 17:50:11 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  770.557023] ata2: hard resetting link
Dec  4 17:50:13 timo-TA790GXB3 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1480870213.5373] device (enp3s0): link connected
Dec  4 17:50:13 timo-TA790GXB3 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1480870213.5383] device (enp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed') [20 30 40]
Dec  4 17:50:13 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  772.683891] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link up
Dec  4 17:50:13 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  772.781816] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
Dec  4 17:50:13 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  772.781830] ata2: EH complete
Dec  4 17:50:13 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  772.789116] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40c0000 action 0xe frozen
Dec  4 17:50:13 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  772.789120] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
Dec  4 17:50:13 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  772.789123] ata2: SError: { CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
Dec  4 17:50:13 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  772.789128] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec  4 17:50:13 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  772.789131] ata2: hard resetting link
Dec  4 17:50:15 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  775.017926] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
Dec  4 17:50:15 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  775.017939] ata2: EH complete
Dec  4 17:50:15 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  775.021237] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40c0000 action 0xe frozen
Dec  4 17:50:15 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  775.021242] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
Dec  4 17:50:15 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  775.021244] ata2: SError: { CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
Dec  4 17:50:15 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  775.021249] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec  4 17:50:15 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  775.021251] ata2: hard resetting link
Dec  4 17:50:18 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  777.246042] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
Dec  4 17:50:18 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  777.246056] ata2: EH complete
Dec  4 17:50:18 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  777.253348] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40c0000 action 0xe frozen
Dec  4 17:50:18 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  777.253352] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
Dec  4 17:50:18 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  777.253354] ata2: SError: { CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
Dec  4 17:50:18 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  777.253359] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec  4 17:50:18 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  777.253361] ata2: hard resetting link
Dec  4 17:50:20 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  779.478160] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
Dec  4 17:50:20 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  779.478173] ata2: EH complete
Dec  4 17:50:20 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  779.485465] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40c0000 action 0xe frozen
Dec  4 17:50:20 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  779.485469] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
Dec  4 17:50:20 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  779.485471] ata2: SError: { CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
Dec  4 17:50:20 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  779.485476] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec  4 17:50:20 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  779.485478] ata2: hard resetting link
Dec  4 17:50:22 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  781.710277] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
Dec  4 17:50:22 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  781.710290] ata2: EH complete
Dec  4 17:50:22 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  781.717581] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40c0000 action 0xe frozen
Dec  4 17:50:22 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  781.717585] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
Dec  4 17:50:22 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  781.717587] ata2: SError: { CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
Dec  4 17:50:22 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  781.717592] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec  4 17:50:22 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  781.717595] ata2: hard resetting link
Dec  4 17:50:24 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  783.942395] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
Dec  4 17:50:24 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  783.942409] ata2: EH complete
Dec  4 17:50:24 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  783.949699] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40c0000 action 0xe frozen
Dec  4 17:50:24 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  783.949703] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
Dec  4 17:50:24 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  783.949705] ata2: SError: { CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
Dec  4 17:50:24 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  783.949710] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec  4 17:50:24 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  783.949712] ata2: hard resetting link
Dec  4 17:50:27 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  786.174509] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
Dec  4 17:50:27 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  786.174523] ata2: EH complete
Dec  4 17:50:27 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  786.181816] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40c0000 action 0xe frozen
Dec  4 17:50:27 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  786.181820] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
Dec  4 17:50:27 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  786.181822] ata2: SError: { CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
Dec  4 17:50:27 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  786.181827] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec  4 17:50:27 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  786.181829] ata2: hard resetting link
Dec  4 17:50:29 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  788.402698] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
Dec  4 17:50:29 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  788.402712] ata2: EH complete
Dec  4 17:50:29 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  788.403326] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40c0000 action 0xe frozen
Dec  4 17:50:29 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  788.403330] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
Dec  4 17:50:29 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  788.403333] ata2: SError: { CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
Dec  4 17:50:29 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  788.403338] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec  4 17:50:29 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  788.403340] ata2: hard resetting link
Dec  4 17:50:31 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  790.618749] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
Dec  4 17:50:31 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  790.618763] ata2: EH complete
Dec  4 17:50:31 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  790.627464] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40c0000 action 0xe frozen
Dec  4 17:50:31 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  790.627468] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
Dec  4 17:50:31 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  790.627470] ata2: SError: { CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
Dec  4 17:50:31 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  790.627475] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec  4 17:50:31 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  790.627477] ata2: hard resetting link
Dec  4 17:50:33 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  792.866864] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
Dec  4 17:50:33 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  792.866878] ata2: EH complete
Dec  4 17:50:33 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  792.872786] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40c0000 action 0xe frozen
Dec  4 17:50:33 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  792.872790] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
Dec  4 17:50:33 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  792.872792] ata2: SError: { CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
Dec  4 17:50:33 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  792.872797] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec  4 17:50:33 timo-TA790GXB3 kernel: [  792.872799] ata2: hard resetting link
Dec  4 17:50:34 timo-TA790GXB3 gnome-session[1069]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x2c0000a (syslog (/v)
```

Comment: I got the same problem - no solution.

Comment: Can you post a portion of the `/var/log/syslog` file after connecting to the ethernet network?

Comment: Sorry for late answer.

Comment: I found this guide as someone else had the same issue. I do not have this card so I cannot test it. However, give it a shot.

https://unixblogger.com/2016/08/11/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a crosspost to my answer on another question about this issue.

[No ethernet connection](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11486/no-ethernet-connection/11491#11491)

This guide may have give you a working solution:

https://unixblogger.com/2016/08/11/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/

Here is an archive of the article:

https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20170410144841/https://unixblogger.com/2016/08/11/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/

Answer (score 1):

My wired connection was constantly reconnecting.

```
Network:   Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k bus-ID: 00:1f.6
           IF: enp0s31f6 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Broadcom BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter driver: wl bus-ID: 07:00.0
           IF: wlp7s0 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-3: Intel I211 Gigabit Network Connection driver: igb v: 5.3.0-k port: c000 bus-ID: 0b:00.0
           IF: enp11s0 state: down mac: <filter>
```

I had to turn off energy efficient ethernet (eee) and wake on lan (wol d) on my wired interfaces with the follwoing command, to make it consistent (you may need to install ethtool first):

```
ethtool --set-eee enp0s31f6 eee off  
ethtool -s enp0s31f6 wol d  
ethtool --set-eee enp11s0 eee off  
ethtool -s enp11s0 wol d
```

To make those changes persistent, yo need to add those commands to /etc/rc.local